# Web App only allows workflow creation on one server in farm, all others fail

Tags: web-application, load-balancing

I have a 3 tier farm, with a clusterd db,  2 app servers and 4 WFE.  The WFE are being load balanced on a netscaler.  We have 3 web apps deployed to the farm.  We are able to create workflows fine on 2 of the web apps but the third one only works on one server which is the primary app server (it still has the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service running).  The AAM are the same for all 3 web apps, but the one we are having problems with is internal only where as the others are available externally.  The app server that the workflows work on is not load balanced.  When I look at the WFE servers and navigate to a subsite and look at all site content it only shows the parent site information and not the subsite information.  When I look at the load balanced url or use the app server it works fine.  Do you think this is a problem with our load balancer?  Should I remove the Web Application Service from the app server?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.